# How can ViewHolder optimize the Adapter ?

Tags: android

I have seen many times that, a custom Adapter usually owns a inner static class `ViewHolder`, so as the google's demo (package `com.example.android.apis.view`.**List14**)

And I have been told that this way can optimize the code efficiency.

Please tell me why `ViewHolder` can optimize the code.

Answer (score 1):

The `ViewHolder` pattern stores each views inside the tag object. This way you can avoid to call `findViewById` every time getView is called, but just retrieve the tag if the convertView is not null.

Edit:

as corretcly pointed out by @jqpubliq

> a major reason avoiding findViewById is desirable is that it traverses
>   the child views of the viewGroup that it is called on until it finds
>   the view with the supplied id. That means this call gets progressively
>   more expensive the more complicated your views are

Comment: As an addendum, a major reason avoiding findViewById is desirable is that it traverses the child views of the viewGroup that it is called on until it finds the view with the supplied id. That means this call gets progressively more expensive the more complicated your views are